# locating and emailing data from a database

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have a site where users clock in and out for work.

I save theres times under the following headings

ID (Key) | Date | Day | userid | Start-time | End-time | total

my issue is every two weeks i need the site to email me all of my employees start and end times for the past two weeks.

---

after connecting to the database i have tried this:

```php
   $period = strtotime($row['period']);

   //start = 14 days previous to current period start
   $start = $period - 1209500;
    if ($result->num_rows > 0 ){

   //period = start of pay period 
   $period = strtotime($row['period']);

   //start = 14 days previous to current period start
   $start = $period - 1209500;



   while ($start < $period){

         $sql = "SELECT * FROM `clocks` WHERE ``date` = '".gmdate("d.m.Y", $start)."'";
         $res = $conn->query($sql);

         if ($res->num_rows > 0){

         while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
            $line = "{$row['userid']} {$row['date']} {$row['start']} {$row['finish']} {$row['breakstart']}";
            echo $line;

          }
            
         } else {

         }
      $start = $start + 86400;


   }
```

---

there are results in my db that should have echo'd as seen before but im not having anything showing. there is also no error log.

thank you for your help

Comment: I know, sorry should have been more specific. if i put 1209600 it goes 1 day too far as it goes to so i did 1209500 to ensure it gives the date i need

Comment: you can use a query like this 

`$start = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($row['period']. ' - 2 weeks'));
$sql = "SELECT * FROM clocks WHERE date > '$start' ";`

Comment: You have an error in your SQL query. You added an extra ( ` ) character before `date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to make this, but one i found that is really simple is saving this in arrays and then send it. Correct my idea if i'm wrong

Issue: You need to send and email of all the logs of your users, when they start, finish and breaks of the last 2 weeks.

Test script [NOTE: I'm using Procedural style]:

```
$gtime = date("d.m.Y"); //date of the day you are running the script
$start = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($gtime. ' - 2 weeks'));
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM clocks WHERE date > '$start'");

$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $data[] = array(
        'userid' => $row["userid"],
        'date' => $row["date"],
        'start' => $row["start"],
        'finish' => $row["finish"],
        'breakstart' => $row["breakstart"]
    );
}
```

then in your body of your email script use the foreach()

```
$mail_body = '<table>';
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $mail_body .= '<tr>';
    $mail_body .= '<td>'.$value ["userid"].'</td>';
    $mail_body  .= '<td>'.$value ["date"].'</td>';
    $mail_body .= '<td>'.$value ["start"].'</td>';
    $mail_body .= '<td>'.$value ["finish"].'</td>';
    $mail_body .= '<td>'.$value ["breakstart"].'</td>';
    $mail_body .= '</tr>';
}
$html .= '</table>';

echo $html;
```

Script need more details, but with this you get an idea,

Comment: This is what I was trying to emulate. I'd gone through trying to make a 2D array to hold all values and got completely lost. Thank you for your help!

Comment: And clearly my SQL knowledge isn't as good as I thought. I didn't even think of using <> operators in querys. Thank you again

Comment: @JackFitton no problem!